# Is an EAPC a “moped” under RTA1988?

Tags: england-and-wales, traffic

The definition given by the road traffic act of moped at s108 seems to encompass electrically assisted Pedal cycles under the EAPC regulations 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 189 The Road Traffic Act 1988](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/189) says:

> (1) For the purposes of the Road Traffic Acts—
>
> ...
>
> (c) an electrically assisted pedal cycle of such a class as may be prescribed by regulations so made,
>
> is to be treated as not being a motor vehicle.

The purpose of [The Electrically Assisted Pedal Cycles (Amendment) Regulations 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/24/contents/made) (see also [Explanatory Memorandum](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2015/24/memorandum/contents)) is to amend the law so that *compliant* EAPC's are *not* classed as motor vehicles.